# How do I trim the values with python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe where the values in one column are represented as '2 days 00:00:00'. I would like to get from this just the value of '2' or '2 days'. How do I do this?

[image]

Comment: `df['days'] = df.days_stay.dt.days`

Comment: Well, if they are strings you know the length of the time never changes so you could just slice the string: `value[0:-9]`

Comment: Please show your code as text rather than screenshots of a notebook

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned what is the desired output but did not mention in what type. You can get it back as a series using either slicing or python regex, please see the following code:

```py
import re

# Option 1:
df['days'].apply(lambda x: x[:6])

# Option 2:
df['days'].apply(lambda x: ''.join(re.findall('(\d{1,} [a-z]+)',x)))
```

if you want it back as a list, you could use list comprehension:

```
[date[:6] for date in list(df['days'])]
```